# Counting several elements inside an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, loops

I just wrote a method that I'm pretty sure is terribly written. I can't figure out if there is a better way to write this in ruby. It's just a simple loop that is counting stuff.

Of course, I could use a select or something like that, but that would require looping twice on my array. Is there a way to increment several variables by looping without declaring the field before the loop? Something like a multiple select, I don't know. It's even worst when I have more counters.

Thank you!

```
failed_tests = 0
passed_tests = 0
tests.each do |test|
  case test.status
  when :failed
    failed_tests += 1
  when :passed
    passed_tests +=1
  end
end
```

Comment: New answer with Ruby-specific *and* Rails+ActiveRecord approach. Independent of number of statuses :)

Comment: Solution chosen, given by @vint-i-vuit :

Hash[tests.group_by(&:status).map{|k,v| [k,v.size]}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Rails 4 ( using 4.0.x here). I would suggest:

```rb
tests.group(:status).count
# -> {'passed' => 2, 'failed' => 34, 'anyotherstatus' => 12}
```

This will group all records by any possible `:status` value, and count each individual ocurrence.

**Edit: adding a Rails-free approach**

```rb
Hash[tests.group_by(&:status).map{|k,v| [k,v.size]}]
```

1. Group by each element's value.
2. Map the grouping to an array of *[value, counter]* pairs.
3. Turn the array of paris into key-values within a Hash, i.e. accessible via `result[1]=2 ...`.

Comment: It's not just dependent on Rails 4. It is dependent on ActiveRecord. And this is the best answer if it is an ActiveRecord Relation.

Comment: Totally agree, although I wonder what is the probability(in terms of global usage of Rails settings) of not using ActiveRecord, considering Rails is being used. *Note: assuming a relational database, maybe too many assumptions... :S*

Comment: Now this is _the_ best answer.

Comment: Since my tests aren't always ActiveRecords, I used your second solution and it's perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could do something clever like this:

```
tests.each_with_object(failed: 0, passed: 0) do |test, memo|
  memo[test.status] += 1
end
# => { failed: 1, passed: 10 }
```

Comment: This is a nice solution although only works with predefined statuses.

Comment: It would be easy enough to make it work with other statuses as well, by passing in `Hash.new(0)` to `each_with_object`. But it would also decrease the readability a bit in this case imo. The OP requirements only talk about two, but improving an always be done when necessary :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `#reduce` method:

```
failed, passed = tests.reduce([0, 0]) do |(failed, passed), test|
  case test.status
  when :failed
    [failed + 1, passed]
  when :passed
    [failed, passed + 1]
  else
    [failed, passed]
  end
end
```

Or with a `Hash` with default value, this will work with any statuses:

```
tests.reduce(Hash.new(0)) do |counter, test|
  counter[test.status] += 1
  counter
end
```

Or even enhancing this with @fivedigit's idea:

```
tests.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |test, counter|
  counter[test.status] += 1
end
```

Comment: You don't need `Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = 0 }`, `Hash.new(0)` will also do! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
hash = test.reduce(Hash.new(0)) { |hash,element| hash[element.status] += 1; hash }
```

this will return a hash with the count of the elements.
ex:

```
class Test
  attr_reader :status

  def initialize
    @status = ['pass', 'failed'].sample
  end
end

array = []
5.times { array.push Test.new }

hash = array.reduce(Hash.new(0)) { |hash,element| hash[element.status] += 1; hash }
```

> => {"failed"=>3, "pass"=>2}

Answer (score -1):

```
res_array = tests.map{|test| test.status}
failed_tests = res_array.count :failed
passed_tests = res_array.count :passed
```